# How to match a string containing an integer possibly followed by whitespace

Tags: typescript

I'm working on the [Beginner/Learner](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#gist/927ccc66ae3022dc64c4f650109b937a-9) problem of [`Type | Treat` 2021 challenge Day 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/type-treat-2021-day-3/), which involves template literal types [introduced in TypeScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types). Specifically, I'm trying to make a function argument type match a string that contains a valid nonnegative integer, possibly followed by zero or more whitespace ( ) characters.

This is what I want:

```
test("0");        // OK
test("1234");     // OK
test("42 ");      // OK
test("100     "); // OK

test("-9");   // type error
test("");     // type error
test(" ");    // type error
test("0123"); // type error
test("who");  // type error
```

This is what I've been working on:

```
type NonZeroDigit = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";
type Digit = "0" | NonZeroDigit;
type ValidDigit<T extends Digit> = T;
type Digits<T extends string> =
    T extends `${ ValidDigit<infer FirstDigit> }${ infer U }`
    ? `${ FirstDigit }${ Digits<U> }`
    : T extends Digit
    ? T
    : "";
type Integer<T extends string> = T extends Digit | `${NonZeroDigit}${Digits<infer U>}` ? T : never;

type Whitespaces<T extends string> =
  T extends ` ${infer U}`
  ? ` ${Whitespaces<U>}`
  : T extends "" | " "
  ? T
  : never;

type Input<T> = T extends `${ Integer<infer I> }${ Whitespaces<infer W> }` ? T : never;
function test<T extends string>(foo: Input<T>);

test("123 "); // type error (why?)
```

However, the `Input<T>` type fails to match strings of the form `"123 "`.
(Note: I'm using `infer` instead of unions to avoid the combinatorial explosion of union types.)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I gave up and checked the [official solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/type-treat-2021-day-4/); and it looks like I went WAY past what the devs anticipated, haha. "over-indexed on the difficulty here" indeed.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that typescript doesn't try every possible head and tail to see if it's a valid integer-whitespace pair. It'll probably just split `"123 "` into `"1"` and `"23 "` and see that `"23 "` isn't valid whitespace. I'd take a drastically different approach with a recursive type here.

Comment: Yeah unless you want to get super clever, the brute force approach is to consume the whole string character by character like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMVy6W).  This can hit recursion limits easily (which can be worked around, especially in TS4.5) but it does the basic operation you're looking for.  Let me know if you want that written up as an answer, or if you have some unmet use case.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thanks, that provides a better insight into type inference in strings

Comment: @jcalz Sure! I'm looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [template literal types to parse strings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#inference-with-template-literals) is sometimes tricky because it's not always obvious where or whether the compiler will match a string to a particular template literal type.  There are various approaches that work:

You can search a string for the first occurrence of a particular character and split the string there, without recursion; for example:

```
type SplitAtSpace<T extends string> = T extends `${infer B} ${infer A}` ? [B, ` ${A}`] : [T, ""];
```

This takes a string and produces a 2-[tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) containing the longest non-space prefix and the rest of the string.  So `SplitAtSpace<"abc def ghi">` is `["abc", " def ghi"]`, and `SplitAtSpace<"nospaces">` is `["nospaces", ""]`.

---

You can also parse a string character by character by putting two placeholders in a row like `` T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? ... `` where `F` will grab the first character and `R` will be the rest of the string.  But to use this generally requires recursion, which has some shallow limits in TS4.4 and below.  TS4.5 will introduce [tail recursion elimination for template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-rc/#tailrec-conditional) which will allow much greater depths as long as you write your recursive types in a particular *tail-recursive* way.  For example:

```
type AsAll<T, U extends string, O extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
    F extends U ? AsAll<R, U, `${O}${F}`> : `${O}${U}` : 
  O;
```

This takes a string `T` (although it's not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) as such to prevent some compiler errors later) and a character or union of characters `U`, and returns a version of `T` which only contains characters from `U`.  If `T` itself only contains characters from `U`, then it returns `T`.  Otherwise, it returns the longest prefix of `T` containing only characters from `U`, followed by one last character of type `U`.  Note that `O`, is an extra type parameter to help with calculation its initial [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) value is the empty string, and accumulates the eventual *output* type.  Here the tail recursion elimination happens because the recursive use of `AsAll<,,>` is itself just `AsAll<,,>` and not `SomeOtherFunction<AsAll<,,>>`.  You can always turn a non-tail-recursive version into a tail-recursive version by storing the partial outputs in another type parameter, like `O`.

---

Okay, armed with that, we can make your `Input<T>` type like this:

```
type Digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";
    
type AsNonNegativeInteger<T> = T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
  F extends "0" ? "0" : F extends Digit ? `${F}${AsAll<R, Digit>}` : Digit : Digit;

type AsValidInput<T extends string> =
  SplitAtSpace<T> extends [infer D, infer W] ? `${AsNonNegativeInteger<D>}${AsAll<W, " ">}` : never
```

Here, `AsNonNegativeInteger<T>` returns a version of `T` which is a valid non-negative integer.  The only valid non-negative integer starting with `"0"` is `"0"` itself.  Otherwise we use `AsAll` to make sure that we return something that is all `Digit` characters.  And if we fail to match anywhere along the line, we return `Digit`.

And then `AsValidInput<T>` splits `T` at the first space with `SplitAtSpace`, and transforms the initial part into a valid non-negative integer, and the final part into a valid all-space string.  If `AsValidInput<T>` evaluates to `T`, then hooray, `T` is valid.  Otherwise, it evaluates to something else that's valid, which can be helpful when showing error messages.

---

Let's try it out:

```
declare function test<T extends string>(t: T extends AsValidInput<T> ? T : AsValidInput<T>): void;
```

Oh, yeah, that's strange, isn't it.  Ideally we'd be able to write `<T extends AsValidInput<T>(t: T) => void` or `<T extends string>(t: ValidInput<T>) => void`, but these formulations often fail to compile (circularity error!) or compile but fail to infer when called (`T` becomes `string` instead of the expected string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)).  The version `T extends F<T> ? T : F<T>` has worked in my experience to have `T` be inferred as a string literal type and still evaluate to `F<T>` when necessary to show good error messages.

All right, *now* let's try it out:

```
test("0");        // OK
test("1234");     // OK
test("42 ");      // OK
test("100     "); // OK
test("4395439583958938593485943985454353"); // okay in 4.5+
```

That last one will fail in TS4.4 and below, but when you try it in TS4.5 and above it should work just fine.

```
test("-9");   // type error
// Argument of type '"-9"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Digit'.

test("");     // type error
// Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Digit'.

test(" ");    // type error
// Argument of type '" "' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// '"2 " | "0 " | "1 " | "3 " | "4 " | "5 " | "6 " | "7 " | "8 " | "9 "

test("0123"); // type error
// Argument of type '"0123"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"0"'.

test("who");  // type error
// Argument of type '"who"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Digit'.

test("456who");  // type error
// Argument of type '"456who"' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// '"4560" | "4561" | "4562" | "4563" | "4564" | "4565" | "4566" | "4567" | "4568" | "4569"'

test("4 2 3"); // type error
// Argument of type '"4 2 3"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"4  "'.
```

Those all look like good error messages to me, in that the expected string is always "close" to the input, at least up until the first failure.

---

So that's probably the approach I'd take.  Note that if you didn't manage to split on the first whitespace, you could still do the whole string character by character, although then you'd have to branch the calculations in a different place.  You'd need to look for a string which either starts with a `"0"` followed by all spaces, of starts with a digit, followed by a string which starts with all digits and then ends with all whitespace, so you'd "switch" from checking digits to checking whitespace upon the first whitespace character.  I won't rewrite that version here as code, but the point is that when searches fail, you should always be able to fall back to character-by-character parsing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBECWBzRpYF5YCIAM3YAfHARgOOwCZycBmG7AFgYFYGA2BgdgYA4GAnNgDcICDFgBlSABs0AQVDSAhgGNoAHgAqsaAA9Q0AHYATAM6wzoAE6IjyAHyZYO-YdMWABgBIA3nYAzaGtYACEAX1g-QODYeXDPWAB+WABtUIAaWES-eM8AXVgALjStLOxsfNEwKDh5M3kZGW0sgFVdA2NzSxs7ZCyAeQ73bqtbe2cKpwxgWBdhrq9ooyCQgDFw5dXYACUE5Ng1hY9YdpT6xuadtqyfXwHN3w3PJxK7h79W-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-ihKRWBzLYqTZPk2BFOU1T1K0nTK30wzrGM6BTL8sSAus2z7M-Z9123VixTcrjgB4vjBOEpKLLgKScDkxAFKU2AVLU5ANO03SYqMkzYn8sUCt3KSnwYH8GBIHAiDoYaKEYMacBYSbsHYGauBm3gZoEHB0ofXAzz-FiyvY9zuriIqfJE5LJLwTaqpqsKGqaqK9IMtqEo6k7LIpNK6JXAB3AALYEtu21yOPywrvJKzqXu+36LpC2r6oi5rovuuL2rM57ytSuz3qYFh2Ahv6XNywGPIOkHfLB8qsZxn6guq6Grrh27WqRx6UZ2-apIw9h8BGimyG5jnqD57H6EF9hmBFtgRc4EWeBF-gRaECS1uA2Anxw-8cokPKia84rSdR2B2ZV2B6Ch0K6vCxrIpaxH4sSsmDaYOZZLsoA)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Typescript don't know where it should to split the string. So, you can help it by point out where it needs to split.

Check out this code:

```js
type NonZeroDigit = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";
type Digit = "0" | NonZeroDigit;
type ValidDigit<T extends Digit> = T;
type Digits<T extends string> =
    T extends `${ ValidDigit<infer FirstDigit> }${ infer U }`
    ? `${ FirstDigit }${ Digits<U> }`
    : T extends Digit
    ? T
    : "";
type Integer<T extends string> = T extends Digit | `${NonZeroDigit}${Digits<infer U>}` ? T : never;

type Whitespaces<T extends string> =
  T extends ` ${infer U}`
  ? ` ${Whitespaces<U>}`
  : T extends "" | " "
  ? T
  : never;

type Input<I extends string, W extends string> = `${Integer<I>}${Whitespaces<W>}`;
type FixedInput<I extends string, W extends string> = Integer<I> | `${Integer<I>} ${Whitespaces<W>}`;
type FixedOriginInput<T extends string> = T extends Integer<infer I> |  `${ Integer<infer I> } ${ Whitespaces<infer W> }` ? T : never

function test<I extends string, W extends string>(foo: Input<I, W>);
function fixedTest<I extends string, W extends string>(foo: FixedInput<I, W>);
function fixedOriginTest<T extends string>(foo: FixedOriginInput<T>);

test("102  "); // I = "1" and W = "02  "
// TS don't know when it need to split


fixedTest("102  "); // I = "102" and W = "  "
fixedOriginTest("102  ");
```